# Plotting a bargraph in django using matplotlib

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

so here is my code. The bargraph is not showing in the dashboard page.
This is my views.py code.

```
expenses = Expense.objects.filter(user=user)
incomes = Income.objects.filter(user=user)
expense_date_list=[]
amount_list=[]
for expense in expenses:
    expense_date=expense.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    amount=expense.amount
    expense_date_list.append(expense_date)
    amount_list.append(amount)
data=plt.bar(expense_date_list, amount_list)
fig=plt.gcf()
buf=io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(buf, format='png')
buf.seek(0)
data=urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64decode(buf.read()))
context = {
   'expenses': expenses,
   'incomes': incomes,
   'user':user,
   'data':data`}
return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context)
```